# MSMQ ReceiveCompleted not firing?

Tags: msmq

I have a simple console app that I'm using MSMQ to store messages before writing to SQL Server.  I'm an MQ newbie so please forgive me if there's a stupid error.  Basically, there is no error thrown and the code just runs straight through without going into the handler...  Any help / guidance hugely appreciated...  code as follows, thanks:-

```
public void MSMQ_GetMessage(string _MQ_Path)
    {
        //set the correct message queue
        MessageQueue _msgQ = new MessageQueue(_MQ_Path, QueueAccessMode.ReceiveAndAdmin);
        //set the format of the message queue
        // _msgQ.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(_TwitterStreamFeed) });
        _msgQ.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(_msgQ_RecieveCompleted);
        _msgQ.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();
        _msgQ.BeginReceive();


    }

    //method to process message
    public void _msgQ_RecieveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //queue that have received a message
        MessageQueue _mq = (MessageQueue)sender;
        try
        {
            //get the messge off the queue
            Message _mqmsg = _mq.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);

            //set the values back into a formatted struct 
            _TwitterStreamFeed _ts = (_TwitterStreamFeed)_mqmsg.Body;

            //now process your SQL....
            _azuresql.writeMessageToStorage(_ts);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        //refresh queue just in case any changes occurred (optional)
        _mq.Refresh();
        //tell MessageQueue to receive next message when it arrives
        _mq.BeginReceive();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, for the novices among us... I rarely use a console app to test stuff out but I have here.  The console app was ending and hence the threads sometimes started, and sometimes completed but nothing could be returned to the console as I hadn't told it to remain open.  to do that just do `Console.ReadKey();`